# Bigquery project-id and dataset-id must not be empty GCP

Tags: google-bigquery, google-colaboratory

I tried to run the below code but I keep getting an error.

```
%%bigquery --project my_project_id df

SELECT 
  COUNT(*) as total_rows
FROM `dataset.table`
```

> ERROR:  400 POST
> https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/my_project_id/jobs:
> ProjectId and DatasetId must be non-empty

Can anyone help out?

Comment: Is it expected that you have a space on your project (rexi df)? Also instead of defining the project using --project, define it after FROM in this format `project_id.dataset_id.table_id`. Can you try this instead?

Comment: The code is supposed to save the output in a variable called 'df', that's why df is there. while the name project's id is rexi. I tried the format you suggested but it generated a different error entirely.

Comment: project_id = '[rexi]'
dataset_id = '[bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum]'
table_id = '[transactions]'


%%bigquery
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) as total_rows
FROM `project_id.dataset_id.table_id`

Answer (score 0):

According to this [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/magics.html#module-google.cloud.bigquery.magics.magics:%7E:text=%25%25bigquery%20%5B%3Cdestination_var%3E%5D%20%5B%2D%2Dproject%20%3Cproject%3E%5D%20%5B%2D%2Duse_legacy_sql%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B%2D%2Dverbose%5D%20%5B%2D%2Dparams%20%3Cparams%3E%5D%0A%3Cquery%3E), you should first input a variable named `df` before your `--project my_project_id` flag to save the results of your query to a variable named `df`. See below query:

```
%%bigquery df --project my_project_id

SELECT 
  COUNT(*) as total_rows
FROM `dataset.table`
```

Sample Output:
[image]